# Locally Hosted Windows Azure Active Directory vs IdentityServer4 for API-Centric Applications

Tags: azure-active-directory, self-hosting, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, api-authorization

Centric application with asp.net core and am concerned about whether to use Active Directory or Identity Server. The thing is i need to be able to run my application in a **closed network** without any connection to the internet but using a local Database. So which is the better choice? In reality i need a more hybrid approach since i will deploy on both closed and open networks.

What are the differences between the two in regards to my needs? 
Which is best for closed networks?

Comment: Your question about the open vs. closed networks is really unrelated to if you should IdentityServer or not.